# How to reset thejit treemap control after the first display?

Tags: c#, json, thejit

I use [thejit treemap](http://thejit.org/static/v20/Jit/Examples/Treemap/example1.html) to display first 50 most frequently used words from a .txt file. My code is deployed [here](http://ntextnetwork.apphb.com).

After the first text upload I receive JSON result and bind it to thejit control. All good so far. However, if I do another upload of a file without manually refreshing the page I get the result where boxes from the first result overlap with boxes from the second upload.

See the picture below.

[image: overlapping of JSON]

**Question:** how do I reset this control to display only new JSON and discard any previous data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Empty the div containing the visualisation before loading in the new data.

On the first line of your `InitTreeMap` function (before the `var tm = new $jit.TM.Squarified({` line), add this:

```
$('#infovis').empty();
```